# Percent change of a IList<T> returning IList<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Given a `List<T>` where `T` is f`loat/decimal/double`, using LINQ, compute the `percent change` of all the values.

This is the definition of `PercentChange` (without `error` checking for example if `a` is `zero`)

```
static double PercentChange(double a, double b)
{
    double result = 0;
    result = (b - a) / a;
 
    return result;
}

var list = new List<double>();
list.Add(2.0);
list.Add(2.5);
list.Add(2.0);
list.Add(1.75);
```

Then using `LINQ` would return a new List one element less, with values:

```
[.25, -.20, -.125]
```

I know I can `loop`. I would like a `functional` version using `LINQ`.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What sort of problems have you run into?

Comment: Try :  var results = list.Skip(1).Select((x, i) => (x - list[i]) / list[i]).ToList();

Comment: The way this question is worded it sounds like homework. If so, please familiarise yourself with [the FAQ about homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/126014).

Comment: Checkout for zero division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd find this approach more readable than a loop, but the LINQ approach would be:

```
list.Zip(list.Skip(1), PercentChange)
```

Outputs:

> [.25, -.2, -.125]

The idea is to take the first list, "zip" it with itself, but skip the first element (so `y` is the next element) and apply your `PercentChange` function on it.  `Zip` will automatically truncate the resulting sequence to the size of the smaller sequence, so you end up with three elements.

Comment: While code works for `List<double>` the question asks for "Given a `List<T>` where T is float/decimal/double," which probably mean some fun with casting is required...

Comment: Except that you can't have two different types in the same `List<T>`, and in this answer, he's invoking `Zip` on a single `List<T>`, so casting is irrelevant.

Comment: @MikeHofer, Alexei just means that if you swap out the `List<double>` with a `List<float>` it won't work as-is.  You'd have to change the types in `PercentChange` to `float` and now it won't work for `double`.  There's no great way to solve this problem generally until we get [generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) which is taking longer to implement than expected and is not due until at least .NET7.

Comment: @KirkWoll Ah. I hadn't considered the signature of `PercentChange` in my earlier comment. You're both right, of course. And the lack of generic math has been a problem since generics were first introduced (and which I've always attributed to the lack of a common base type for numerics but am more than likely ridiculously wrong about).

Answer (score 2):

Several solutions are available, I prefer the following one, combining [LINQs Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) with [LINQS Enumerable.Skip](https://Enumerable.Skip)

```
var result = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => (b - a) / a);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

which prints

> 0.25, -0.2, -0.125

This very compact solution allows calculation of your list like visualized here:

```
a:    2.0        2.5        2.0       1.75
b:    2.5        2.0        1.75
res:  0.25      -0.2       -0.125
```